# Why do I get the error that the 'split' attribute is missing when I run runmodwsgi?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am in the process of moving the django page to a new server. Due to complications in the apache server configuration, I used mod_wsgi-express integrated into virtualenv python. According to the instructions found on this page: https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/#description , I added mod_wsgi.server to installed Django applications and run the command `python manage.py runmodwsgi`. Unfortunately, in response I get an error which pastes below. I would be very grateful for any help and explanation why this problem appeared.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SAGI-B/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/g####/.venvs/sa###/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/g####/.venvs/sa###/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/g####/.venvs/sa###/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/g####/.venvs/sa###/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/g####/.venvs/sa###/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/management/commands/runmodwsgi.py", line 71, in handle
    fields = wsgi_application.split('.')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The Django version I use is 1.10.7 (I know, I should upgrade - I'm in the process). In the settings.py configuration file I didn't find the line with WSGI_APPLICATION = 'xyz.wsgi.application'. Could this be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absence of a line with `WSGI_APPLICATION = ...` in the settings.py file was the reason for the failure.